# C# intersect two list of strings with a pattern

Tags: c#, regex, list, intersection

I have two list of strings like this:

```
var entities= new List<string>(){"101", "102", "103",}; 
var files= new List<string>(){"101_F05_20101001.csv", "102_F05_20101001.csv", "201_F05_20101001.csv", "202_F05_20101001.csv"};
```

I want to get the result of intersecting them following this pattern:

ID_F05_YYYYMMDD.csv

Where ID should match one or more items in the entities list.

I have written the following code:

```
var list = files
    .Where(x => entities.Any(y => x.Contains(y) && x.Substring(0, y.Length) == y))
    .ToList();
```

Running code [here](https://ideone.com/HcbqK3).

But I wonder if this can be improved using a regex like this one:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(\d*)_F05_\d*\.csv$");
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, $@"^(?:{string.Join("|", entities)})_F05_\d*\.csv$"))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is not working, not matches are found

Comment: BTW, `csv` or `cvs`? Your input data contains `cvs`, but you tried `csv` in the pattern.

Comment: csv format, will fix

Comment: It's working! file format was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, $@"^(?:{string.Join("|", entities)})_F05_\d*\.csv$"))
```

The regex will look like `^(?:101|102|103)_F05_\d*\.csv$` given your current input data and it will match

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:101|102|103)` - a non-capturing group that matches `101`, `102` or `103`
- `_F05_` - a literal string
- `\d*` - 0 or more digits
- `\.csv` - `.csv` string
- `$` - end of string

Note you do not need to regex escape the `entities` if they are numeric. Else, you need to use `string.Join("|", entities.Select(Regex.Escape))`.

[C# code demo](https://ideone.com/3bGBVK):

```
var entities= new List<string>(){"101", "102", "103",}; 
var files= new List<string>(){"101_F05_20101001.csv", "102_F05_20101001.csv", "201_F05_20101001.csv", "202_F05_20101001.csv"};

var pat = $@"^(?:{string.Join("|", entities)})_F05_\d*\.csv$";

var list = files
        .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, pat))
        .ToList();

foreach (var s in list) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output:

```
101_F05_20101001.csv
102_F05_20101001.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

I choose to use a little bit more linq to solve it:

```
        var entities = new List<string>() { "101", "102", "103", };
        var files = new List<string>() { "101_F05_20101001.cvs", "102_F05_20101001.cvs", "201_F05_20101001.cvs", "202_F05_20101001.cvs" };
        var regex = new Regex(@"^(\d*)_F05_\d*\.cvs$");

        var result = entities.SelectMany(e => files.Select(f =>
        {
            var match = regex.Match(f);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                if (match.Groups.Count > 1)
                {
                    if (match.Groups[1].Value == e) return f;
                }
            }

            return "";
        })).Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Comment: which is the regex pattern? could you include it, please?

Comment: I just used yours :-) ( except for the typo  ( csv -> cvs)